# Convert a specific cell into a column Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I want to populate a new column with a specific cell using Power Query exactly like this:
[from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJXNF.png) -->[to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAGys.png)

This task has been taught here: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/convert-a-cell-value-into-a-column-with-power-query/

but I start with a structured table within the worksheet and so the Power Query only reads the table, leaving out the specific cells that I need (which are B2 and B4), as displayed here.
[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxqdL.png)
[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulCTE.png)

So how can I do the same thing?

Comment: Convert the cell to a named range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete example, starting with a worksheet like this:

[image: worksheet]

Click on the specific cell containing the value with which you want to populate a new column (B2), enter a name in the name box (*cellCategory*), and press Enter. Right-click the cell and click on *Get Data from Table/Range...* which opens the Power Query Editor.

[image: category]

Open the Advanced Editor, delete everything, enter this line of code and click on Done:

```
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="cellCategory"]}[Content][Column1]{0}
```

[image: advanced_editor]

Named ranges that are loaded in Power Query are automatically transformed to a table. In the line above, `[Column1]{0}` accesses the value located in Column1 at row index 0 of that table which contains a single cell. So now you have a query that returns the content of that cell.

If your main table isn't yet loaded to Power Query, return to the worksheet, right-click on your table and click on *Get Data from Table/Range...*.

Now, as shown in Step 5 of the linked tutorial, go to the ribbon tab Add Column, click on the button Custom Column, and add a new column named *Category* filled with the *cellCategory* query value by entering `cellCategory` and clicking on OK:

[image: add_column]

Here is the result:

[image: result]